# How to convert YYYYMMDD string to date in databricks SQL end point?

Tags: date, databricks, date-conversion, databricks-sql, string-to-datetime

How to convert YYYYMMDD string to date in databricks SQL end point?

Input values:- 1. 20230804

```
           2. 20230805
```

output values :- 1. 2023-08-04

```
             2. 2023-08-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  TO_DATE(your_column_name, 'yyyyMMdd') as formatted_date
FROM
  your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST('2023-08-04' AS DATE), 'dd MM yyyy') AS formatted_date;
```

Result will be `2023-08-04`

If you want month in letters abbreviated to three characters

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE('20230804', 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy MMM dd') AS formatted_date;
```

Result will be `2023-Aug-04`
If you want Full Name of the month

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE('20230804', 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy MMMM dd') AS formatted_date;
```

Result will be `2023-August-04`